# Is there a possibility to use a dynamic id in SVG fill=url(#)

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, linear-gradients

I'm creating a svg icon to fill with a color percentage from linearGradient.

In linearGradient I'm creating id's dynamically and want to make use of the same dynamically created id's in

I tried interpolation fill={url(`#linear${i}`)} which didn't work and not sure if this is the right way to use in SVG.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
<div *ngFor="let block of filteredBlocks; let i = index">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         height="100px"
         viewBox="0 0 24 24"
         width="100px"
         fill="url(#'linear' + i)">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient [attr.id]="'linear' + i">
          <stop [attr.offset]="block.percent + '%'" stop-color="green"/>
          <stop [attr.offset]="(100 - block.percent) + '%'" stop-color="white"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
     <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
     <path d="M17 4h3v16h-3V4zM5 14h3v6H5v-6zm6-5h3v11h-3V9z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to make it working:

- use interpolation on attribute binding

  ```
  attr.fill="url(#linear{{i}})"
  ```
- use string concatentation on attribute binding

  ```
  [attr.fill]="'url(#linear' + i + ')'"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a native JS Web Component, supported in all modern browsers,

- no unique ID required if you use shadowDOM
- If you don't want shadowDOM, stick on  `new Date()/1` to force a new unique ID

```js
customElements.define("svg-icon",class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    let offset = this.getAttribute("offset") || 5;
    let color = this.getAttribute("color") || "green";
    let id = "gradient"; // + (new Date()/1)
    this
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"}) // leave out for no shadowDOM
        .innerHTML = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
     height="100px" width="100px"         
     fill="url(#${id})">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="${id}">
          <stop offset="${offset}%" stop-color="${color}"/>
          <stop offset="${100 - offset}%" stop-color="white"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
     <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
     <path d="M17 4h3v16h-3V4zM5 14h3v6H5v-6zm6-5h3v11h-3V9z"/>
    </svg>`
    }
});
```

```html
<svg-icon></svg-icon>
<svg-icon offset="20"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon color="red"></svg-icon>
```