# Why can't I target my custom-defined HTML elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-component, custom-element, css-import

In my HTML, I've got:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="js/components/custom.js"></script> 
...
<custom></custom>
```

In `custom.js`, say I've defined:

```
class Custom extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
  const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        @import url('/css/styles.css');
      </style>
      ...
    `
  }
}

customElements.define('custom', Custom)
```

In `styles.css`, when I define styles, **they work**. But I can't do something like

```
custom img {

}
```

to target an `img` inside `custom`. I have to use wrappers like `div.custom-contents` to target elements within.

Is this a known limitation perhaps with `@import`s like this, custom elements in general, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is **mandatory for custom elements that the name must consist** of at least one letter, followed by a `-` dash, then at least one other letter. **Your web component will not work if you don't conform to that requirement.**

Your component uses shadow DOM. No outside styles affect the shadow DOM (other than inheritance), and no styles in the shadow DOM affect elements outside of of your component. This is the main concept behind shadow DOM - components bring their styling, and don't affect other elements on the page they're used in.

Also, you shouldn't attach the shadow DOM in the `connectedCallback`. That should always be done in the `constructor`.

You can use the `part` attribute along with the [`::part`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) pseudo element to allow styling from the outside.

Comment: creating a shadowRoot in the ``connectedCallback`` is fine; provided you are aware that callback will execute again when moving the component around in the DOM.

Comment: Technically it's fine; but I can hardly think of a reason why you'd not want it in the constructor. I haven't had a case where it would have been desirable to have it in the connectedCallback in 4+ years of developing web components as my main job task. Can you think of a case where constant recreation of the shadow root would be desirable? If not, it just creates the hassle of either cleaning it up in the disconnectedCallback, or having to safeguard the creation of it in the connectedCallback.

Comment: Just about every time you want to create dynamic content _once_. With or without attributes which you **shouldn't** access in the ``constructor``. Many of my [svg] answers here on SO show using the ``connectedCallback`` only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805170/is-there-a-possibility-to-use-a-dynamic-id-in-svg-fill-url/70807372#70807372  I must be crazy, I've been doing this for 5+ Web Components years.

Comment: _"cleaning it up in the disconnectedCallback"_ WHAT needs to be cleaned up?

Comment: OP here. I do have a hyphen in my actual component name, forgot to translate that requirement in this sample code. Thanks for the other pointers. Does the element itself count as "outside of your component" though? Like I can style a `<p>` tag using `p { ... }` in CSS. But can't style `<custom-element>` using `custom-element { ... }` in CSS?

Comment: I just checked, adding `custom-element { ... }` right below _or instead of_ the `@import` line also didn't work. I'm trying to apply a `text-align` directly to the element's tag if that matters. Of course I can apply a class or add a child container, but that feels redundant.

Comment: The custom element itself can be styled from the outside, e.g. you can assign dimension, padding, margin etc. Other than with inherited properties not defined inside your shadow root, you cannot affect styling of elements in the shadow DOM, as my answer explains.