# How to pass a "desired" id to an inline SVG made of multiple g?

Tags: html, svg, dom, inline

I'm using an SVG pre-provided to me, and defined using `<defs>` and `<g>` elements similar to that one below (I have removed most of the *path* elements content for simplicity):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"viewBox="0 0 96 96" fill="none">
  <defs>
    <path id="singlecolor" d="M94.9588 20.6182L86.2126 5.20824V5H84.9631H68.5119H66.6377L66.4295"/>
    <g id="multicolor">
      <path d="M48 73.2971L52.7543 81.8L57.6 90.3943H48H38.4L43.1543 81.8L48 73.2971Z" fill="#E92D78" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g id="multicolor-onLight">
    <use href="#multicolor"/>
  </g>
  <g id="multicolor-onDark">
    <use href="#multicolor"/>
  </g>
  <g id="singlecolor-onDark">
    <use href="#singlecolor"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Today, this SVG is served as a standalone file and rendered in an `img` tag, and the `src` attribute contains an anchor tag, such as `src='myfile.svg#multicolor-onLight'`. This "selects" what gets eventually rendered, in that case the path defined under then `<g>` with id "multicolor".

In the future, I would like to resuse the same SVG but inline in my code. Is there a way to reuse the same SVG code as inline SVG, and more specifically, how to select which `<g>` element will be rendered?

I'm putting the `<svg>` inline in a `<div>` tag and tried to set Ids on both, but that made no difference. Seems only the "first" defined path is rendered...

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: The thing is that SVGs are built ,for me by an other organization, and used by multiple parties. I want to use SVGs inline to enjoy advanced CSS theming, but if I have to modify the SVG code, I will have maintenance issues down the road... Does this clarify @mplungjan ? And is your comment a way to suggest this might not be possible, or does not make sense?

Comment: It does sound like you want your cake and eat it too. Can you show an example of a working path with an ID that you want to use, because it is not clear how the svg ad an image can have multiple paths that you choose from if it is inline

Comment: Here is an example... If you go to https://veneer.hp.com/platforms/web/components/_next/static/media/veneer.87c57164.svg#singlecolor-onLight you will see an SVG rendered as wireframe. Now if you change URL to https://veneer.hp.com/platforms/web/components/_next/static/media/veneer.87c57164.svg#multicolor-onLight you see the same SVG but with a different color scheme. In each case, the <svg> content is the same. The URL is use as a "selector" of sort. Now if I put that <svg> inside a <div>, how can I express which "flavor" I will render?

Answer (score 1):

Create the inline SVG with your own native `<my-svg>` JavaScript Web Component,
configurable with attributes, and you do not needs all those `<defs>`

```js
customElements.define("my-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback(){
    this.style.display    = "inline-block";
    this.style.width      = "100px";
    this.style.background = "pink";
    this.innerHTML = 
          `<svg viewBox="0 0 96 96" style="vertical-align:top">
            <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" 
                    fill="${this.getAttribute("fill") || "red"}"></circle>
          </svg>`
  }
});
```

```html
<my-svg></my-svg>
<my-svg fill="yellow"></my-svg>
<my-svg fill="blue"></my-svg>
```

Your `id` issue with multiple SVGs having the same `id` is because inline SVGs will use the **first** defined `id` on the page. (no different how `getElementById` finds the **first** id)

To work around that

- either create a unique `id` in the Web Component
- or add an extra shadowRoot to your Web Component to encapsulate all content.

For both see: [Is there a possibility to use a dynamic id in SVG fill=url(#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805170/is-there-a-possibility-to-use-a-dynamic-id-in-svg-fill-url/70807372#70807372)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this does not really address my question... (1) I'm not facing an issue with mutliple elements having the same id, and (2) this needs me to rewrite the SVG which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like I found a way to solve this. Posting here if that can be useful to someone else...

So, in the example I posted, the SVG contains a group with the following Ids: `multicolor-onLight`, `multicolor-onDark` and `singleColor-onDark`. As mentioned, when the SVG is rendered via an `img` tag, the `src` of the image acts as a selector.

When rendering inline, the solution I used is to run some JavaScript to "trim" all `SVG>g` with a different id than the one I'm looking for. The code looks like (searching for id `multicolor-onDark` in that example):

```
   let gSet = document.querySelector('svg>g')
   for (let i = 0; i < gSet.length; i++) {
     if (gSet[i].id !== 'multicolor-onDark') gSet[i].remove()
   }
```

Of course this "destroy" the source SVG so it must be "reloaded" if a different id is to be selected. It can indeed be done conveniently by embedding this in a custom element.